# How to convert point in any CRS to cartesian XYZ given the proj4 string?

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, proj, c++, moon

I have GeoTIFFs of other celestial bodies, such as the moon, and am writing a program in C/C++.  I cannot use `GDAL` but I can use `libgeotiff`, `libtiff`, and `proj`.  Some GeoTIFFs are in a polar stereographic projection while others are in a cylindrical projection.

I need to take these GeoTIFFs and convert them into a set of 3d cartesian (xyz) points.  As an example of what one of these datasets looks like take the [LDEM_4](http://imbrium.mit.edu/BROWSE/LOLA_GDR/CYLINDRICAL/ELEVATION/) cylindrical projection map.  (If you actually wanted to use it you'd simply need to download both the `LDEM_4.IMG` and `LDEM_4.LBL` files, then you can use `gdal_translate` to convert it to a geotiff by running: `gdal_translate -of GTiff LDEM_4.LBL LDEM_4.tif`).  **This is a global model of the moon, and so what I would like to happen to this particular DEM is that it be converted into a 3d point cloud of the moon**

So far, the first thing I'm doing is to obtain the model tie points and pixel scales using:

```
TIFF* tif = XTIFFOpen(filepath.c_str(), "r");
GTIF* gtif = GTIFNew(tif);

int16_t count;
auto modelTiePoint = new double[6];
auto pixelScale = new double[3];

TIFFGetField(tif, GTIFF_TIEPOINTS, &count, &modelTiePoints);
TIFFGetField(tif, GTIFF_PIXELSCALE, &count, &pixelScale);
```

Printing the `modelTiePoint` and `pixelScale` arrays gives:

```
0 0 0 -5.4582e+06 2.7291e+06 0

7580.84 7580.84 0
```

(Which matches with the (2,3) and (1,3) arrays I see when I use `GTIFPrint()`)

The next thing I do is read the pixel data itself into an `std::vector<float>` of heights (I can dump this to a csv and confirm this is being done correctly).

Next I get the proj4 string by using:

```
GTIFDefn* psDefn = GTIFAllocDefn();
GTIFGetDefn(gtif, psDefn);
char* proj4cstr = GTIFGetProj4Defn(psDefn);
```

This sets `proj4cstr` to a value of:

```
+proj=eqc +lat_0=0.000000000 +lon_0=180.000000000 +lat_ts=0.000000000 +x_0=0.000 +y_0=0.000 +a=1737400.000 +b=1737400.000 +units=m
```

My final step is to try to transform each pixel coordinate to a cartesian xyz coordinate.  For this, I am trying the following:

```
PJ_AREA* area = NULL;
PJ_CONTEXT* ctx = proj_context_create();
const char* target_crs = "+proj=cart +units=m";
PJ* P = proj_create_crs_to_crs(ctx, proj4cstr, target_crs, area);

for (uint32_t j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < width; i++){
        idx = i + j*width;

        PJ_COORD c_in;
        c_in.xyz.x = (static_cast<double>(i) * pixelScale[0]) + modelTiePoint[3];
        c_in.xyz.y = (static_cast<double>(j) * pixelScale[1]) + modelTiePoint[4];
        c_in.xyz.z = heightData[idx];
                
        PJ_COORD c_out = proj_trans(P, PJ_FWD, c_in);

        fout << c_out.xyz.x << ", " << c_out.xyz.y << ", " << c_out.z << "\n";
    }
}
```

(Note: I'm currently dumping the outputs to a `.csv` file just so its easier for me to visibly inspect by bringing it into matlab/python and plotting it)

This runs, but it just produces a rectangular grid of points spanning from (-5458200,2729100) to (5450620,8179730), with the z-data being the (correct) elevation values.  What I want (from this particular case) would be a 3d model of the moon, and so it should be spherical.

This is all a bit outside of my area of expertise.  I believe I'm on the right track but I have no idea what is wrong with my inputs.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**TLDR: I need a C/C++ which takes geotiffs that contain either cylindrical or polar stereographic projected data, and converts it into 3d point cloud**

Comment: If you Z values match what's in the raster, then definitely something's going wrong. "cart" is 3D Cartesian with XYZ axes are from the center of the sphere/ellipsoid being used, so the Z values won't match. They're no longer going to be height above surface. The X and Y values should max out at R=1737400.0. PROJ doc says that cart takes +ellps and defaults to GRS80. Maybe that's the issue?